# JList/JScrollPane Don't Resize to Adapt to Narrower Cell Contents

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have troubles getting a `JList` look properly in a `JScrollPane`. My data is shown in a two-step kind of fashion.

In a first run the raw data is shown and it may look like this:

```
|----------------------------|
| XX                       Y |
| XXXXXX                  YY |
| XX                       Y |
| XXXXXXXXXXXXXX           Y |
| XX                       Y |
|----------------------------|
```

So there's a `JLabel` on the left, a `Box.createHorizontalGlue()` and a `JLabel` on the right.

The nature of the data allows longer values and, therefore, may make it look like this, i.e. the cell becomes too wide:

```
|----------------------------|
| XX                         |   Y
| XXXXXX                     |  YY
| XX                         |   Y
| XXXXXXXXXXXXXX             |   Y
| XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XX Y
| XX                         |   Y
|----------------------------|
```

Due to that I have a horizontal scrollbar, which is fine.

During the update-run the X-stuff usually becomes shorter, resulting in this:

```
|----------------------------|
| XX                         |   Y
| XXXX                       |  YY
| XX                         |   Y
| XXXXXX                     |   Y
| XXXXXXXXXXXX               |   Y
| XX                         |   Y
|----------------------------|
```

And that's the problem: the cell isn't resized. The result should look like the first example where the right `JLabel` appears on the right hand side of the `JList` and there is no horizontal scrollbar.

Here's how I create the `JList` and `JScrollPane`:

```
private JList<Person> personList;

private void createVisual() {
  JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
  mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
  frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);

  mainPanel.add(new JScrollPane(personList = createList()));
}

private JList<Person> createList() {
  JList<Person> list = new JList<>();
  list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    ...
  });
  list.setCellRenderer((JList<? extends Person> list, Person person, int index, boolean selected, boolean hasFocus) -> {
    JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel();
    infoPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(infoPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    infoPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 5, 0, 5));

    JLabel personInfo = new JLabel((index + 1) + ": " + buildInfo(person));
    if (isMarked(person)) {
      personInfo.setFont(personInfo.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
    }
    infoPanel.add(personInfo);
    infoPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    infoPanel.add(new JLabel(buildStats(person)));

    if (selected) {
      infoPanel.setBackground(new Color(35, 185, 255));
      infoPanel.setOpaque(true);
    } else {
      infoPanel.setOpaque(false);
    }
    return infoPanel;
  });
  list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
  return list;
}
```

The update-run contains a repaint of the `JList`, which I call every time I updated the POJO behind a cell:

```
personList.repaint();
```

While watching it I can see that the cells are updated one by one, but the `JList` or `JScrollPane` don't change the width at all.

I'm not too familiar with Swing and I tried to use `validate()`, `invalidate()`, `revalidate()`, `repaint()` in various places without actually knowing what they do. So I'm stuck here.

How do I force the `JList`/`JScrollPane` to change their sizes to get something like in the first example?

EDIT:
Long story short: It was finally decided by the powers that be that I can use a `JTable`. In other words this question has become obsolete.

Comment: Have you tried calling `revalidate()` whenever the list data has changed?

Comment: Is the problem the custom renderer or something else in your code? Basic debugging tip, first get the logic working using standard classes, then start adding custom code to see if it still works. So, implement a `toString()` method in your `Person` class to simply display the "xxxxx" value. As the value changes, the scrollbar size should change as required. If this works, then you know the problem is with your renderer. If it doesn't work, then the problem is elsewhere in your code

Comment: @VGR on which component?

Comment: `I tried to use validate(), invalidate(), revalidate(), repaint()` - revalidate() basically invokes the layout manager on the component. Normally this is done automatically when you invoke setter methods on the component. In your case you are changing the data in the model, indirectly without using model methods, so I would try to revalidate the JList after all the data has changed. The repaint() can then be invoked to make sure the JList is painted properly. I have never used invalidate() or validate(), those are old AWT methods.

Comment: @camickr Nope, that didn't make it better.

Comment: @camickr Regarding the cell renderer: Well, I use the horizontal glue, but even without it the result is the same. Other than that I don't know what I could do differently in the cell renderer.

Comment: Oh and BTW, the two `JLabel`s are only filled with strings. So it's two strings on two `JLabel`s  where I already noticed that the left one changes its size after the `repaint()`.

Comment: `Other than that I don't know what I could do differently in the cell renderer` - you missed the whole point of my first comment. The point is to NOT use a custom renderer and see if the scrollbars resizing works. That is, is the preferred width of the JList changing as the data changes?

Comment: @camickr Ah, OK. Well, without my cell renderer I only see the POJO's `toString()`, but only constantly for the first 111 rows. Then while I keep scrolling down the strings keep reappearing roughly in the top third of the visible part of the list while the remainder is always rendered empty!?!? The last 150 rows appear normally again. Now this is really weird... I can only think of some sort of buffering here, but where?

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: @Ansharja This has become obsolete, feel free to vote to close this question.